# Should my RESTful service update the full posted object graph or should I force clients to post each object?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a web api service, say I have endpoint:

https://mySvc.com/api/companies

If a company can have multiple locations, when posting to the endpoint above, should I try to save the entire object graph (i.e. company and locations) from the single post or should I only update the company and force the client to post the locations for said company?

I feel like working with the entire object graph can make my business logic and validation much easier and straight forward, but this also feels pretty un-RESTful.

What **and why** should I do in a scenario like that?

Comment: What does this endpoint do?

Comment: REST supports the concept of PATCH, where you update some part of the representation. Returning part of the object graph in GET is a common pattern, you could do it with media types or you could use a parameter in the query string, which is possibly less RESTy but easier.

Comment: @MotiAzu This endpoint would have your typical get, post, put, and delete methods. My question is if you were to post/put a full company object graph with its location objects and any other child objects, should I create/update JUST the company or create/update the entire object graph?

Comment: I don't think it's un-restful to include arrays in your sent data. If there is another justification to making the client post multiple requests then go ahead, but I don't think doing it in one requests violates any best practices. Could you explain what makes this feel un-RESTful?

Comment: Resource expansion is a common technique in REST.  I don't think it is un-RESTful either.  If you have multiple objects that need to be updated in a single transaction...having the client maintain that and worry about conforming to your business logic will be much harder to maintain.